# igraph: get and permute vertex ids

Tags: r, igraph

In R package igrpah, how are ids assigned to each vertex? Is there a similar function like `get.edge.ids` that we can get vertex id from a vertex, e.g. `g = graph.ring(3); V(g)$name=LETTERS[1:3]`, so `get.vertex.ids(V(g)['A'])` will return the id of the vertex 'A', which is 1 in this example. And how can we change the id of the vertices? Sure we cannot change the id of only one node, but can we permute the vertex ids?

Comment: The vertex id is just the element number in the vector `V(g)`. So, `as.numeric(V(g)["A"])` should return the id.

Comment: Yes this works. But is there anyway to permute the vertices ids?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are trying to do. Do you want to plot them in a different order? Can't you just permute the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `permute.vertices()` to permute the IDs of the vertices. Note that the vertex IDs are always integers between 1 and |V| in R (where |V| is the number of vertices).